# iOS Podfile error: undefined method 'source'

Tags: ios, ruby, cocoapods

I am currently getting the following error when running pod install:

```
[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: undefined method `source' for #<Pod::Podfile:0x007fcf91b8c7a8>. Updating CocoaPods might fix the issue.

 #  from /Users/preston/Work/Test/Podfile:1
 #  -------------------------------------------
 >  source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
 #  platform :ios, '8.0'
 #  -------------------------------------------
```

I have tried the following:

- pod repo remove master; pod setup
- rm -rf ~/.cocoapods; pod setup
- sudo gem uninstall cocoapods; sudo gem install cocoapods

After running the last bullet point I ran pod setup and got the following:

```
Setting up CocoaPods master repo
Already up-to-date.

CocoaPods 0.36.0 is available.
To update use: [sudo] gem install cocoapods

Setup completed (read-only access)
```

Which is confusing because I just updated.

Evening after running all of these commands I am still getting the above error. Does anyone know what might be going wrong?

**Edit:**

Here is my Podfile. However everything worked on another computer but not on mine:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!
```

Comment: could you post your Podfile

Comment: I have posted my Podfile.